# Replace TypeScript namespaces with ES2015 modules

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I've recently reconfigured my typescript setup and now I get errors that are cause through the rule [no-namespace](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v2.34.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-namespace.md).

My current setup with namespaces is the following:

class that exports something:

```js
namespace MyNamespace {
    export class Foo {}
    export class Bar {}
}
```

class that imports:

```js
import MyNamespace from './my-namespace';

// access classes
MyNamespace.Foo;
MyNamespace.Bar;
```

I want to replace this setup with the recommended ES2015 modules (I *do not* want to simply disable the rule). How would I do that? Optimally, I want to keep my current import syntax, I do not particularly like the syntax `import {Foo, Bar} from './my-namespace'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [official answer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing).

In your example, you can replace the namespaces with modules like so:

1. Remove the namespace syntax:

```
    //namespace MyNamespace {   <-- remove this line
    export class Foo {}
    export class Bar {}
    //}                         <-- remove this line
```

2. In the file where you need the types, use a named import:

```
import * as MyNamespace from './my-namespace';

// access classes
MyNamespace.Foo;
MyNamespace.Bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to namespace your imports, use the `* as ...` import syntax:

```
export class Foo {}
export class Bar {}
```

```
import * as MyNamespace from './my-namespace';

// access classes
MyNamespace.Foo;
MyNamespace.Bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `export` , you can do sth as @cyr_x mentioned. Just want to point out using `export default` is also ok to use namespace.

```
export {default as YourCustomisedName} from '<your file path>'
```